# Text overlapping with absolute position. Safari & chrome

Tags: css, css-position

I am running into this Safari problem where space of an absolute positioned <span> isn't recognized in Safari. It works perfect in both Opera and Chrome.

I have no idea how to solve this. I tried all kind of height calc combinations. Here is the code:

```
<h1>
                
     <span>
            <span class="rw-words rw-words-1>Sentence with three long words
            </br>    
            <span class="">Rotating word 1</span>
            <span class="">Rotating word 2</span>
     </span>  
                    
</h1>

<div>A lot of additional text</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.rw-words-1 span{
animation: rotateWordsFirst 8s linear infinite 0s;
}

@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
2% { opacity: 1;   }
40% { opacity: 1;   }
53% { opacity: 0;  }
100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.rw-words{ } 

.rw-words span{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
color: #6b969d;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
animation-delay: 4s; 
color: #6b889d;
}
```

So there is a three word sentence and below there are two absolute positioned words which change from on into the other (rotating words animation).

The problem is that the "more text" below begins after Sentence 1 and is therefore overlapping the "Rotating words" in Safari  while chrome and firefox puts it correctly below the Rotating words.

A fixed height of the h1 container doesn't work because "sentence 1" wraps a lot.

So basically I need to set the height of the h1 or span correctly.

The height has to be

```
width: fit-content;
```

plus one line-height to account for the absolute spans. But I can't find a way to make that work in css.

I am not very experienced and the solution might be simple.

best regards

Martin

**UPDATE Feb 8th 2023 based on replies:**

I found a simple solution which works.
I simply added the div right under the absolute spans and added relative position and top margin of 1.5em.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix those errors first.

Comment: I did, see my answer below. The errors did not fix the problem. Its about Safari not accepting the height of the absolute positioned span.

Comment: @Rayray he means fix your question!

Answer (score -1):

You have errors in your HTML.

1. You forgot to close the attribute value in your `<span>` with the class `rw-words rw-words-1`.
2. `<br>` has no closing tag. You can either write it as an open tag 
    or you can close it where you opened it `<br />`, but you can't close it like this `</br>` 
   Try it like this:

```html
<h1>
                
     <span>
            <span class="rw-words rw-words-1">Sentence with three long words
            <br>    
            <span class="">Rotating word 1</span>
            <span class="">Rotating word 2</span>
     </span>  
                    
</h1>

<div>A lot of additional text</div>
```

Comment: There is also no such thing as `</br>`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that